# jx command to delete the PV's (Persistent Volumes) associated with a helm release

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-x

I am trying to delete all the resources of a deployed micro service like Deployments, services, PVC's and PV's associated with a helm release using the "jx step helm delete {release_name} -n {db-backup}".

This deletes all the resources except the PV's. And I am unable to use the traditional kubernetes commands in the Jenkinsfile to delete the PV's.

Please let me know the jx command to delete PV's.

Comment: seems it was fixed [here](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/pull/832/commits/320336b0e741b3cedbad3f4ed655547eb654875a) , try using latest version

Comment: I think that fix is to delete the PVC's but I am trying to delete the PV's. The PVC' are being deleted by "jx step helm delete" command